# Why is it bad for neural networks to output indices?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Let's say you wanted to train a neural network to output `N` indices (maybe it's sorting an array). There are at least 2 possible ways one might sample from this network:

1. Project the `N, dim` vector to `N, 1` and round the outputs
2. Project the `N, dim` vector to an `N, N` vector and do softmax on the rows / columns to select the correct index at each position

Apparently, it is better to use method 2 instead of method 1. But ... I don't have good intuition for why this is the case.